# Accessibility Rules Checked by IOS Accessibility Inspector

Tags: ios, accessibility

We've been using the [Apple Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html) to check our accessibility of our app but we were wondering if anyone knows what are all the rules the accessibility inspector checks against?

[image: Accessibility Inspector]

For example, when I run an audit against our app, it can tell me that the element has no description or contrast failed. But what is the full rule set that the inspector checks against? Expanding the options shows this:

[image: Options it checks?]

It would be helpful to know the full ruleset of the list above so that we can understand what can be tested using that tool for a11y and what needs to be manually checked. Also if there was a way to map what the Accessibility Inspector checked to the [WCAG rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/), that would be even better

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that the checks you are referring to are from the *Accessibility Verifier*?

Comment: Interesting that you would you like to refer directly to the WCAG, as they are not originally intended for native apps. Are you aware of the [WCAG2ICT Task Force](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/task-forces/wcag2ict/)? There is standards like the [EN 301 549](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EN_301_549) along with Europe’s Accessibility Directive, which explicitly take WCAG Rules and apply them to information and communications technology in general, including native apps (chapter *11 Software*).

Comment: Sorry I meant [the European Accessibility Act](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Accessibility_Act)

Comment: @andy I don't see any accessibility verifier options on my accessibility inspector, so I wonder if that is legacy? I updated my post to show what I see on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

[the Accessibility Verifier documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH210-SW4) provides an explicit list of checks the *Accessibility Verifier* performs:

> - Parent/Child. This test checks the integrity of the accessibility hierarchy by making sure each parent-child pair forms a closed loop. For example, if a child listed in a parent object’s accessibilityChildren property does not refer to that object as its parent, this parent-child pair is invalid. Invalid parent-child pairs can prevent an accessibility client from correctly traversing an app’s accessibility hierarchy.
> - Window. This test checks that all objects contained in a window contain a reference to that window in their accessibilityWindow property. An object contained in a window is not necessarily the child of that window, but it should refer to its containing window as a convenience for accessibility clients.
> - Missing AXDescription. This test checks the element’s accessibilityLabel property. All accessible elements must provide some context-specific, descriptive label.
> - Role Verification. This test verifies that an accessibility object implements all the properties and methods required for its role.

The latter would be found in the corresponding role documentation, for example [NSAccessibilityButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilitybutton)

What is interesting, though, is that you mention contrast checks, which are not listed here.

This looks like Apple is simply verifying against **their own criteria or rules**, which probably are based on other official standards. I wouldn’t expect Apple to guide you to other external sources.

#### Mapping to WCAG

The [WCAG2ICT Task Force](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/task-forces/wcag2ict/) works on applicability of the WCAG to software in general, the [European Accessibility requirements for ICT products and services (EN 301 549)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EN_301_549) explicitly apply WCAG’s Success Criteria to software in chapter 11, and the [U.S. Access Board provides a mapping of Section 508 Criteria to the WCAG](https://www.access-board.gov/ict/wcag2ict.html).

Therefore it is more likely you would find a mapping to one of the intermediary, legislative documents than to the WCAG directly.